# Can compile Kotlin code in android Java project

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use Kotlin classes from some other project into a Java project. This Kotlin code also has a service. Based on suggestions found on Kotlin website I have directly copied the Kotlin packages to Java project and configured Kotlin runtime.
But after sync I am getting following errors.

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'Cake VPN'.
    > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
       > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0.
         Required by:
             project :
          > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally. However we cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0:
              - gradle70JavadocElements
              - gradle70RuntimeElements
              - gradle70SourcesElements
              - gradle71JavadocElements
              - gradle71RuntimeElements
              - gradle71SourcesElements
              - gradle75JavadocElements
              - gradle75RuntimeElements
              - gradle75SourcesElements
              - gradle76JavadocElements
              - gradle76RuntimeElements
              - gradle76SourcesElements
              - javadocElements
              - runtimeElementsWithFixedAttribute
              - sourcesElements
            All of them match the consumer attributes:
              - Variant 'gradle70JavadocElements' capability org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
                  - Unmatched attributes:
                      - Provides documentation but the consumer didn't ask for it
                      - Provides javadocs but the consumer didn't ask for it
                      - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                      - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                      - Provides attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.0' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                      - Provides release status but the consumer didn't ask for it
```

Also here is my module level build.gradle

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        ext {
            kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
        }
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()


        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
            classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Here is the app level build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 33
        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 33
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            applicationId 'com.cybexo.vpn'
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        buildFeatures {
            dataBinding true
            // for view binding:
            // viewBinding true
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        buildToolsVersion '30.0.1'
    }

    dependencies {

        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
        implementation "com.wireguard.android:tunnel:1.0.20211029"

        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.0'

        // Glide image loader
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
        implementation project(path: ':appLib')
    }
```

I am not able to figure out how to resolve these errors.
Any help appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure what's causing your error, but using the `buildscript` block instead of a `plugins` block is the hard way. Replace

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

with

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0'
}
```

And if you want to fully eliminate the `buildscript` block, [read this article](https://stefma.medium.com/its-time-to-ditch-the-buildscript-block-a1ab12e0d9ce). New Android Studio projects from the new project wizard no longer use `buildscript` if I recall correctly.

You might also need to add this inside your `android` block in the second Gradle file:

```
android {

    //...

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}
```

and remove the redundant line at the top:

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
```

Comment: Hi did the above changes using build script but no luck and errors remained same

Comment: If I configure Kotlin version 1.6 which is min then it builds but then there is a compile time error "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0."

Comment: Did you try `kotlin_version = '1.8.0'`? You have to use at least the highest version being used by any of your dependencies.

Comment: Any version above 1.6 throws all above errors

Comment: I notice the error mentions compatibility with Java 11. Is it possible one of your dependencies is compiled with Kotlin to target JDK 11? What happens if you change `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` and `targetCompatability` to target version 11 instead of 8?

Comment: I tried but didn't help , changed it in Kotlin options as well as java

Comment: I'm out of ideas. :(

Comment: I believe the toolchain is pretty much messed up here even if they say android studio will take care of things , it just didn't happen